# Unable to render an array into table after splice and unshift in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-table, splice

I am not sure if I am doing some mistake or is it a default behaviour. I am using splice/unshift to add a new element on top of a 2d array and then try to render that array to a table.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1[i].length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
          var r = arr1[j][i];
          dt(r);
      }
      dttop(i);
  }

  function dt(x) {
      if (isFinite(x) == true) {
          numeric++;
      } else {
          str++;
      }
  }

  function dttop(x) {
      if (numeric > str)
          arr1.splice(0, 0, "number");
      else
          arr1.splice(0, 0, "string");
  }
  alert(arr1); // alert--1  
   // render the result into html table
  s = '<table border=0>';
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
      s = s + '<tr>';
      for (var j = 0; j < arr1[i].length; j++) {
          s = s + '<td><font size="1" face="Verdana">' + arr1[i][j] + '</font></td>';
      }
      s = s + '</tr>';
  }
  s = s + '</table>';
  renderArea.innerHTML = s;
```

So, when I use javascript splice() or unshift(). I get an output like this[image]
But, if I do alert 1 then it gives me result like this [image]
which proves that it is adding the extra bits from splice function but not rendering as html..

Please help

Comment: Might I ask what you are using the `isFinite()` function to determine?

Comment: to check if the value is numeric or not

Comment: I would suggest using `typeof` rather than `isFinite()`.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see you are using `.splice()` to add the string `"number"` or `"string"` to the start of the `arr1` array. Doing this means that as you loop through to add the values the code tries to access an index of the strings (`arr1[i][j]`), resulting in `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using splice/unshift to add a new element on top of a 2d array and then try to render that array to a table.

The splice() method returns an array containing the elements that were removed from the original array. If you want to prepend values given a two dimensional array:

```
var num_arr = [[1,2,3]];
```

A simpler solution would be:

```
json_arr = JSON.stringify(num_arr).replace("[[","[0,[");
```

And rendering to a table would be:

```
function rowMaster(value,index)
  {
  return "<tr><td>value</td></tr>".replace("value",value);
  }

function parseFarce(value,index)
  {
  if(typeof value == "number") return "<th>value</th>".replace("value",value);

  else if(delete value.length === false && delete value[-1] === true && JSON.stringify(([]).constructor().valueOf()) === "[]") 
    {
    return value.map(rowMaster);
    }

  else
    {
    return value;
    }
  }

JSON.parse(json_arr).map(parseFarce);
```

**References**

- [JSON.parse Examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Examples)