# Is there any method to optimize the code of dynamic table creation Using JavaScript from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, html, css

I want to dynamically create a table from javascript and this code works fine. Is there any other method to optimize the following code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table,th,td {
  border : 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td {
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<script src="expt1.js" ></script>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Show</button>
<table id="demo"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
var myFunction = function() {
        var emp = '[{ "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith" }, { "firstName": "Peter", "lastName": "Jason" }, { "firstName": "Alice", "lastName": "Ray" }]';
            var obj = JSON.parse(emp);
            var table = "<tr><th>firstName</th><th>lastName</th></tr>";
           for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                table += "<tr><td>" + obj[i].firstName + "</td><td>" +
                obj[i].lastName + "</td></tr>";
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
        }
```

Comment: refer this answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180382/convert-json-data-to-a-html-table

Comment: If this is working code that you want suggestions for improvement, then perhaps you should post it at http://codereview.stackexchange.com and follow their posting rules.

Comment: Oh thanku..!! I would rather post there.

Comment: If you are looking for an alternate solution, read these articles . https://teamtreehouse.com/community/html-table-from-json-store-using-pure-javascript-no-jquery     and refer this plugin http://www.dynatable.com/  .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to render an array into table after splice and unshift in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23173003/unable-to-render-an-array-into-table-after-splice-and-unshift-in-javascript)